# C++11 Capture Member Variable in Lambda

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a member variable defined as:

HWND WindowHandle.

I'm trying to capture the variable and assign to it in the Lambda. So the compiler gave me a warning and suggested that I capture "this". I did, but now the Handle is only valid within the Lambda :S Inother words, it is NULL outside of the Lambda.

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        HWND WindowHandle;

    public:
        Foo();
        void MakeWindow(.......);
        HWND GetWindowHandle() {return WindowHandle;};
};

Foo::Foo(){}

Foo::MakeWindow(.......)
{
    Thread = std::thread([ClassName, Title, Width, Height, this]{
                    WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), Title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
                    if(WindowHandle)
                    {
                        ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
                        MSG msg;
                        while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
                            DispatchMessage(&msg);
                    }
                });
}


int main()
{
    Foo F;
    F.MakeWindow(........);
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<(F.GetWindowHandle() == NULL);  //writes true.
}
```

The above creates the window perfectly fine! It's just the Handle is null. How can I get the Handle from within the Lambda to my class Member?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your code has a race condition. By the time you check the value in main(), the thread has not run yet, so WindowHandle is still NULL.

Unless you didn't actually start the thread yet. In that case, since the thread hasn't executed, WindowHandle is still NULL.

In any event, you need to synchronize access to WindowHandle between threads with a mutex.

Comment: You're right! I just put a big sleep and it turns out it was not NULL. Gahh now I have to go dive into Mutexes :l

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Actually, while mutexes solve this problem it’s probably a better idea to clear up your code design: the outside world should not require information such as the window handle anyway, under normal circumstances. Isolate dependencies and don’t provide internals to the outside world. When other code wants something from your window, let them call a method on `Foo` rather than exposing the window handle.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Mutexes are pretty easy, especially when you use a RAII mutex locker, like `std::lock_guard` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), which helps avoid some very common newbie-mistakes that result in deadlocks.

Comment: Hmm This is true. I thought of not providing access to the handle but the only way for my Pen Class to draw on the Window is to obtain a handle to it and it obtains this handle through that Foo class in the OP. Either way, I think the outside world would be able to do FindWindow and get the Handle & DC without me providing the handle in the first place? Unless of course it can't because of the thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can only capture local variables, i.e., something declared in the function where the lambda is created or one of its argument. In a member function when accessing a member `x` you are actually accessing `this->x` with `this` being the implicit pointer to the object passed to the member function. The lambda would, thus, capture `this` rather than `x`. To capture a member you'll need to create a local variable holding it and then capture this variable, e.g.:

```
auto&& tmpWindowHandle = this->WindowHandle; // ... or just WindowHandle
```

... and then you'd capture `tmpWindowHandle` in your lambda function.

Since your lambda function doesn't show any synchronization it seems that your `GetWindowHandle()` also doesn't have any synchronization and your calling thread probably access the `WindowHandle` member before you it is set by the thread: You'll need some form of synchronization, be it a `join()` or some form of mutexex or condition variables before you can call use the `WindowHandle` from some other thread. The overall setup looks like a good application of a `std::future<...>`: It is intended to run a function potentially concurrently and then block until the result is necessary when the result is actually accessed.

Comment: That is not correct. You can capture `this` in a lambda and get access to every member of the object in which the lambda is defined.

Comment: @Ravadre That is half-correct. When you capture `this`, you are not capturing all members. You are only capturing `this`, a single object pointer.

Comment: @NikosC.: Please read my response and tell me where I claim that you *cannot* capture `this`! In fact, I even state that instead of the member variable `this` is captured. ... and it is definitely true that you *cannot* capture member variables.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong but wasn’t there a suggestion from some people on the committee to (normally?) only ever capture via `[&]`, `[=]` or `[this]`? In other words, not to capture individual locals but rather the whole scope because the compiler can sort out what to capture quite well by itself?

Comment: Then I suppose your answer is confusing because it doesn't actually answer the OP's question :-/ It sounds like you're saying that the OP can't get to WindowHandle by capturing `this`, but rather has to capture a reference to it.

Comment: @NikosC. You are right, I wanted to keep my comment short and I unintentionally made it unclear; I've deleted it, as your comment states this more correct.

Comment: @NikosC.: Well, it answered the question about capturing member variables and how to actually do this. I have added a paragraph to point at the missing synchronization, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the `WindowHandle` on different thread. So what probably happens is that your new thread has not yet started and you are checking if `WindowHandle` has changed already. Also, you should protect access to `WindowHandle` with some mutex or other construct, otherwise you will have a race condition.